# You can not run the php script

Tags: php

I have a problem when you run a script from php the problem is that it doesn't do what must be done, this is the php code

```
? php
echo "starting execution";
echo exec("./sc");
?>
```

and in the code of the script this is sc

```
mv text.txt /var/www/files/
```

does not work does not move the file archive there is I've added the chmod permismos but doesn't appreciate any suggestion

Comment: The user that is executing the php script doesn't have permission to move that file. Find out what user is executing the php script, most likely `www-data` and grant it `rw` permission on the file you're trying to move. However your question is very unclear... Are you running this via command line? A browser? What's the actual code you're trying to run? It appears you're attempting to run this php script from a random directory that also contains a bash script that will move a file from that specific directory into `/var/www/files`

Comment: And if all that is true then the real question is: why?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest to execute the script file manually from command line(console) and check if the script file is working properly. If that doesn't work, then it won't work in php too.

Try:

```
echo "starting execution";
echo exec("./sc", $output);
var_dump($output);
```

contents of sc :

```
mv text.txt /var/www/files/ 2>&1
```

If the file is not moved, it must throw an error which you should be able to see in `$output`.

My guess would be that the error must be related to permission.